# Naming of the General Rust Raw String Literal Technique

Tags: rust, programming-languages

In Rust, a [raw string literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals) (emphasis mine):

> ...start with the character U+0072 (r), **followed by fewer than 256 of the character U+0023 (#)** and a U+0022 (double-quote) character. The raw string body can contain any sequence of Unicode characters and is terminated only by another U+0022 (double-quote) character, **followed by the same number of U+0023 (#) characters that preceded the opening U+0022** (double-quote) character.

Which allows for raw string literals to be written like so:

```rust
let greeting = r#"Hello"#;
let salutation = r##"Goodbye"##;
let call_me = r##"#555-5555"##;
// etc.
```

What I'm looking for it the name of this general programming language design paradigm. As best I can describe it, it's one where a variable number of characters (in Rust's case, the pound sign ("#")) act as a sort of "start and stop delimiter" over the contents of a string body to differentiate between the end of the string's definition, and the contents of the body.

Looking at the [grammar for Rust](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/grammar.html#character-and-string-literals), I couldn't find any production name that would give me any hints with regards as to what to call this, only:

> raw_string : '"' raw_string_body '"' | '#' raw_string '#' ;

Comment: I don't think this is a "paradigm" or that it necessarily has (or needs) a spcial name. I think you already gave it a pretty good name: delimiters. Maybe "matching delimiters" because they have to be the same at the start and end. Maybe "variable matching delimiters" because the number of pound signs is arbitrary. Maybe "variable matching string delimiters" because they only apply to string literals.

Comment: Do you know another language that also has this feature? Even within Rust's source I didn't see a name for it beyond them being referred to as the string's "hashes". But if we're allowed to make stuff up, I'd say the string is "reinforced" by more #s.

Comment: @kmdreko - Lua has something similar for block comments/strings, both of which employ double square brackets as starting ("[[") and ending ("]]") delimeters. In Lua's case, 0+ equals ("=") could be used in a similar nature to Rust's raw string literals:

```lua
str = [==[
  <html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
]==]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call these “paired delimiters for raw strings.”

The use of custom delimiters goes back to `sed` and `vi`, which allow custom delimiters in the used of `s` (substitution) and similar expressions.  Perl adopted this approach in addition with paired delimiters in `s` and `tr` expressions (e.g., `s{.*}{foo}g`) and some other contexts, and Ruby has the same thing in some cases as well.

Rust *doesn't* have custom delimiters, but it does have a sort of paired delimiter as you've described.  [Perl uses the phrase “paired delimiters” in describing the use of things like `qw« foo bar baz »`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlexperiment#Extra-paired-delimiters-for-quote-like-operators), and this is essentially that syntax, just much more restricted.  So these are effectively just paired delimiters.